# What is an elegant solution to ensure inserts are limited to the root ownership in a hierarchical tree in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

So I have the following hierarchical database structure:

1. Table *person* has columns *id* and some other fields.
2. Table *car* has columns *id*, *owner* (with a foreign key constraint    to person.id) and some other field
3. Table *bumpersticker* has columns *id*, *car* (with a foreign key    constraint to car.id) and some other fields

I want to INSERT a row in to *bumpersticker* and have values to populate the row. I also have a person.id value of the person trying to add the bumpersticker.

What is the best practice to ensure that the *car.owner* value selected from the *bumpersticker.car* is in fact the same person.id as I have?

I guess one obvious way is to first execute a select query, on the car table and select the car.owner and validate that this value is the same value as the id of the person trying to add the bumpersticker and then execute an insert query.

but this seems like something there must be an elegant solution to in MySQL. at least not having to do two separate queries.

Most thankful for your help!

Comment: You could do the `INSERT` in a stored procedure. Add the `person.id` value as a parameter to the procedure, and it can then perform this check before inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert from a `SELECT` query that tests if the owner matches the criteria

```
INSERT INTO bumpersticker (car, sticker_text)
SELECT c.id, "If you can read this you're too close"
FROM car AS c
WHERE c.id = @car_id AND c.owner = @person_id
```

`@car_id` is the ID of the car you're adding the bumpersticker for, and `@person_id` is the ID of the user doing the insert. If the owner ID doesn't match, the `SELECT` query will return no rows, so nothing gets inserted.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65fe/1)

Comment: Thanks! I receive operand should contain 1 column(s) error when I try this. If I however INSERT INTO bumpersticker (car, sticker_text) VALUES ((SELECT c.id FROM car AS c
WHERE c.id = @car_id AND c.owner = @person_id),"If you can read this you're too close")  it works great. thanks

Comment: It works, I added a demo on sqlfiddle. It sounds like you added an extra `VALUES` that doesn't belong.